# SurveyJS : Disabling the automatic Thank You Message in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, survey, surveyjs

I have implemented a SurveyJs (https://surveyjs.io) survey on our react application using survey-react (https://www.npmjs.com/package/survey-react). Everything works fine but when the survey is submitted we are POSTing the data to a DB using axios and receiving a reply from the API if successful or not.

The issue is that I have implemented the survey in a modal and surveyjs seems to have a "Thank You" page that I can't find a way to disable. So when I submit I have a component re-render twice (the default thank you page and my API success/fail response). I can overwrite the text by using "completedHtml" on the JSON file but I can't disable it. The issue is that the jump on the modal doesn't look good even when I overwrite it with something like "Processig Survey..."

My Modal Code:

```
<Dialog
                open={dialogOpen}
                onClose={handleClose}
                aria-labelledby="Your Opinion Matters"
                aria-describedby="Short Customer Survey"
                className={classes.modal}
            >
                <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
                    {(status === '') ?
                        `We would like to hear from you`
                        :
                        `Thank You`
                    }
                </DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    {surveyActive ?
                        <Survey.Survey model={model} onComplete={onComplete} />
                        :
                        <span style={{fontSize: '1.5em', color: '#999'}}>{status}</span>
                    }
                </DialogContent>
                {(status !== '') &&
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                        Close
                    </Button>
                </DialogActions>
                }
            </Dialog>
```

My Survey API Call and Handling:

```
const setSurveyData = (data, options) => {
    const authToken = sessionStorage.token;

    return axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/users/survey',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`,
        },
        data: {
            survey: data
        }
    })
        .then(res => {
            const data = res.data;
            setStatus(data.msg);
             setSurveyActive(false);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            catchAxios(err);
        })
};

// run on survey complete
const onComplete = (survey, options) => {
    return setSurveyData(survey.data, options)
};

const handleOpen = () => {
    setDialogOpen(true);
    setSurveyActive(true);
};

const handleClose = () => {
    setDialogOpen(false);
    setStatus('');
};
```

I've been looking at this for about 5 hours now and drawing a blank... I've tried everything I could think of. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

PS: Forgot to mention that I have already tried passing the showCompletedPage parameter as false via the JSON, however, since the survey is on a modal, it still shows the modal title (and only the title) which is worse.

Comment: Typically when I post here I find the solution within a few minutes. For future reference what I have done was control the modal opening inside the API response instead. It was quite silly and simple but was passing me, onComplete will close the dialog and then I re-open it after the API response comes in. Silly me! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the [showCompletedPage](https://www.surveyjs.io/Documentation/Library/?id=surveymodel#showCompletedPage) of a survey to false.

Comment: Thanks for the reply TSV, yes I had tried that but then I had no reply with the code I was using, I was looking for a solution in Survey.JS but my problem was on my own code structure. Thanks though.